# IOS/Iphone : how to open a pdf link without .pdf extension in iphone browser

Tags: ios, iphone, pdf

I come across pdf link on my web page .this pdf link open and download perfectly on desktop and android.
but in iphone browser (safari/chrome/firefox) the download does not happen and view in corrupted format.
I see the problem is the pdf link has no .pdf extension, other pdf link that have .pdf extension working fine.

What is the way to open pdf file without extension in iphone browser

Answer (score 1):

It is probably a problem with the page and you cannot do much for the extension.
Just try to open it with iBooks or save it to an app where you can change the extension to pdf.